# Is there a third-party builder besides LLVM and LLVM-GCC?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, compiler-construction

I wish to build a lib (written in C language) with a thrid-party builder(not LLVM or GCC), and use it in my Xcode project. The lib itself can indeed be compiled with LLVM or GCC, but my manager wants to know whether it can be compiled by other compilers because he want to get a best performance.

PS: I used the ARM compiler (armcc 5.01 Build 94, in ARM DS-5 IDE) and also Keil uVision 4.54 on my machine. The compilers work well on compiling but their generation cannot be used as a lib for Xcode, for the formating of their compiled object are not correct, and I cannot figure out how to compile and run this binary on iOS.

Comment: The key is the format of the archive, and whether llvm can link to it. Personally I do not believe you can find another compiler that will produce significantly faster code than llvm/clang - the optimizer is set by default to -Os for Release, but you can set it higher to get more optimization. Also, you can re-write sections of the code in assembler or using NEON to get really high performance if you want.

Comment: What practical reason would you have for using something other than LLVM or LLVM-GCC? Given that LLVM is what Apple has put all its effort behind, you're not going to find another compiler out there that is anywhere near as well tuned for targeting iOS devices. I'd tell your manager that you should be investing your efforts elsewhere.

Comment: (in addition to David H): Intel compilers or other (expensive) HPC compilers maybe, but I doubt that they will be supported on Apple platforms.